# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb on VSTS

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Locally all my test run fine but when do a build on VSTS I get this error.

```
##[error]System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
```

Though the nuget restore build step says:

```
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.3.0.1.
```

and

```
Adding package 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.3.0.1' to folder 'D:\a\1\s\packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.3.0.1' to folder 'D:\a\1\s\packages'
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new simple project? If so, can you share it on the OneDrive?

Comment: No I cant create new projects on VSTS

Comment: I can create the error locally when removing the 3 Owin packages form the test project

Comment: Is it possible to turn on Assembly binding logging on VSTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by adding this dummy class

```
 public class Dummy
 {
     internal void LoadThisAssembly()
     {
         Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler httpHanlder = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler();           
     }
 }
```

I guess the test project would not copy the assembly unless it was actually being used